# Find Target int inside Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been trying to debug this code for the past 2 hours. The function should simply find the target in the array elements.
This is the question :

//Write a function that takes the following prototype:
`bool f2(int a[], int N, int target);`
The function tests whether the target appears in the integer array `a` (of size `N`) at least one time. If
yes, the function returns true; otherwise, it returns false.
Test the function with a main program that defines an array of five integers and initializes them
within the main program, calling the function `f2()` and displaying appropriate message based on the
return value of `f2()`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool f2(int a[], int n, int target, int& index);

int main(){
    int arr[5];
    int target;
    int index = 0;

    cout << " Enter array elements: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << " x[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << " Enter target to search for : ";
    cin >> target;

    if (f2(arr, 5, target, index))
        cout << " Target " << target << " found in index " << index << endl;
    else 
        cout << " NOT found ! " << endl;

    return 1;
}

bool f2(int a[], int N, int target, int& index){

    int j = 0;
    while (j < N)
    {
        if (target == a[j]) {
            index = j;
            cout << "list[" << j << "]" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot your question...

Comment: Also it's obvious you didn't use the debugger.

Comment: BTW, your prototype don't match the requirement

Comment: [`std::find(a, a + n, target)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Answer (score 1):

`return false;` should be outside of the loop, else you just test first element:

```
bool f2(int a[], int N, int target, int& index)
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j < N)
    {
        if (target == a[j]) {
            index = j;
            cout << "list[" << j << "]" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return false; // should be here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool f2(int a[], int N, int target, int& index){

int j = 0;
while( j<N)
{
    if (target == a[j]) {
        index = j;
        cout << "list[" << j << "]" << endl;
        return true;
    }


    j++;
}
return false; //should be here

}
```

you return false value inside loop

Answer (score 0):

As other members have suggested, `return false;` should be outside the loop.

You can solve this problem using recursion also but As πάντα-ῥεῖ[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96)] suggested, its not a good idea. It may lead to stack overflow errors on bigger arrays quickly.

```
bool checkNumber(int input[], int size, int target){
    if(size == 0){
        return false;
    }
    if(input[size-1] == target){
        return true;
    }
    bool answer = checkNumber(input, size-1, target);
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Recursion is rarely a good idea. It may lead to stack overflow errors on bigger arrays quickly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for the valuable suggestion. I am a beginner, thought it might give OP a new way to solve the given problem. I will update the answer.